# How to specify the HTTPS port number in IIS Express 10 with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

With IIS Express 10 and Visual Studio 2015 I am able to set a Web API project to use SSL from the project properties window (F4) by setting `SSL Enabled` to `True`. By doing so, Visual Studio and IIS Express will generate a random port number and it will be displayed in `SSL URL` field. Then I am able to launch the project with HTTPS protocol.
[image]

However, I need a specific SSL port for my project, then I tried different approaches:

- Directly modify the `applicationihost.config` file from `.vs/config` folder for chaning the port number
- Modify the `Project Url` field from project properties tab

[image]
[image]

But unfortunately, none of them is working, in both case launching the project results in a "Site can't be reached" error.

Comment: You need a tool like Jexus Manager to set up HTTPS binding, https://www.jexusmanager.com And then edit csproj file to match the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Port 443 (Standard SSL-Port) for HTTP use 80

Comment: I tried, and also did not work. But actually my desired ports are not standard one.